# Does grep function detect tab delimiter?

Tags: linux, grep

I've got a question here.
I have a raw file A which contains the column as below:

```
LG111222332626 2626 T C G A

LG111222332626 467789 G C G G
.....
```

The column are separated by delimiter "TAB".
My question is How to retrieve my desire line from raw file A if i were given a list B like as below:

```
LG111222332626 2626 

LG111222334768 1212
.........
```

I was wondering if grep function able to do something like this

```
grep -e "LG111222332626\t2626"
```

(but grep seems doesn't recognised `\t` here, what is the proper way to do this.)

Thanks all. Sorry if the way i express my problem is a bit confusing, hope you read me =)

Comment: Use `$'...'` instead of `"..."` to get bash to interpret the tab escape before bash gets it.

Comment: Or just escape the slash: grep -e "\\t"

Comment: So `grep -e $'LG111222332626\t2626'` would work as @Kevin suggested. Kevin I think you could post this as an answer, because it solves the problem.

Answer (score 6):

As indicated by [Kevin in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016084/does-grep-function-detect-tab-delimiter#comment24590780_17016084):

Use `$'...'` instead of `"..."` to get bash to interpret the tab escape before bash gets it.

In this case,

```
grep -e $'LG111222332626\t2626'
```

will work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestiosn and i got it now using the -P option.

The commmand sounds as follow:

```
grep -P "LG111222332626"\\t"2626" file_A
```